# Why do my wcf application can not use and save session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Here is the interface and class of my wcf application.At first,I want to get the sessionId in my method by

`string sessionId=OperationContext.Current.SessionId`

But I find that sessionId is always null.So I try to use and save the asp.net session successfully like

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("testSession", "testSession");
```

in one method.And In other method I try to get the `testSession`,but it is null.

```
var myTestSession= HttpContext.Current.Session["testSession"];
```

What is wrong with my code?Why does the SessionId always be null?

**My wcf interface**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface ITestSession
{
[OperationContract]
string SetSession(string sessionvalue);
[OperationContract]
string GetSession();
}
```

**My wcf class**

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
//[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TestSession: ITestSession
{
 public string  SetSession(string sessionvalue)
 {
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("testSession", sessionvalue);
  return sessionvalue;
 }
 public   string  GetSession(string sessionvalue)
  {
  var testValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["testSession"];
    if (testValue ==null)
     return "null value";
     else
    return testValue;
     }
    }
  }
```

I have try to add or remove the configuration like  `<!--aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"-->`,but still get the null session.How to fix it?

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />       
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: WCF is stateless by design. You should avoid sessions if you can. But if you really have to, at least don't try to use _ASP.NET_ sessions.

Comment: @chris, Can you tell me why don't try to use ASP.NET sessions?I have config it in the config file using `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"`.

Comment: This document describes, among other things, the difference between WCF and ASP.NET sessions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I do really need to use sessions,no matter wcf or asp.net sessions.But both are fail for me.I still do not know why `OperationContext.Current.SessionId` is null in wcf sessions?

Comment: I trust you read the documentation thoroughly? Just to be sure: WCF sessions have to be explicitly intiated by the _client_.

Comment: If you are wondering why sessions generally are a bad thing: Among other issues, above all they make your service less scaleable.

Comment: @chris,I have a wcf,and not everyone can call the wcf function.So I think I can use session to store the user that have the permission to call this wcf funcion.And if the session is null,he must have not the permission.It means that I have a methodA to verify all the caller.And the methodB is the really method that called by caller.

Comment: If you are using sessions for authorization: WCF offers much better, more scaleable ways to implement authentication & authorization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59600/discussion-between-sarly-and-chris).

Comment: @chris,Can you give me some example abount more scaleable ways to implement authentication & authorization?
I use session in MVC and it is OK,but when I change it to wcf,it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WCF sessions are not at all like HTTP sessions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040(v=vs.110).aspx) They are explicitly opened and closed. `HttpContext` doesn't apply at all because WCF isn't necessarily HTTP based.

Answer (score 0):

1) to manage sessions in WCF , think to manage InstanceContextMode of your service, take a look on this [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per)

2) if i understand you have a method call that will begin your session before to authorize call of other methods, if this is your need, you can use IsTerminating and IsInitiating method attributs as described here :

http://dadraraghu.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/setting-the-initialization-and-termination-of-the-wcf-session/

http://www.remondo.net/managing-wcf-session-lifetime-isinitiating-isterminating/